# How to display the time in 24-hour format in timeCellComponent using <dx-scheduler>

Tags: angular, devextreme

I have time like this '2:00 PM' and I want to get it like this '14:00'. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to this post https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t495138/dxscheduler-how-to-show-a-time-scale-in-the-24-hour-format# it was 2 years ago, there are some workaround for example

```
timeCellTemplate={e =>new Date(e.date).toLocaleString("en-GB", {hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"})}
```

also the support team provide some example using localization here

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Localization/UsingIntl/Angular/Light/

hope this answer your question